# IOS 6 -display images and its details in the same view in landscape mode

Tags: ios6

How to display images and details in same view?

In landscape mode my image view covers half of the view and the other half screen to display  details. When i swipe my images, its related details has to be displayed.

can anyone provide code or some tutorial for this in ios.

Comment: I have no idea what to do.I just wanted to know how gallery works in ios.I wanted to implement the gallery functionality in the same as how gallery functionality works in android.

Comment: you can make use of UICollectionView if you want to make the stack of the images as in android gallery and customise the UICollectionViewCell.